# Custom "generic" OAuth 2.0 Bearer Authentication to secure a Web API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory

I'm currently using **UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication** to secure a Web API. This is fine at the moment as the test environments use Azure AD Identity.

However, the production environment will use a different Auth provider (OAuth 2 compliant).

What I'm looking for is to convert the following Azure AD specific code:

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"]
                });
```

To something more generic that will still work with Azure AD for the moment but will be easy to configure for a different Auth provider in the future. For example:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication
            (
                new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
                {
                    //...
                }
            );
```

How can the latter be implemented to work with Azure AD and also be "generic" enough for other OAuth 2 compliant providers?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth2 doesn't define a format for access tokens. Azure AD uses JWT, and advertises its coordinates through various metadata documents, but there is no guarantee that other providers will do the same (and in fact they do not most of the time). The spec is simply not detailed enough to allow for such generic component.

Comment: vibronet thanks. Ok, then at least how could I get the same behaviour with Azure AD using the UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication wrapper?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Apologies, I made a mistake on the previous comment. What I want is to continue with Azure AD for the moment but without using UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication. I want to implement the same functionality using the "standard" UseOAuthBearerAuthentication.

Comment: The Azure AD specific middleware implementation is based on the Oauth2Bearer middleware, if you take a look at its source code you'll see how it does it: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory/WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions.cs